# TypeScript: Error inside Promise not being caught

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, es6-promise, spfx

I am developing a SPFx WebPart using TypeScript.

I have a function to get a team by name (get() returns also a promise):

```
  public getTeamChannelByName(teamId: string, channelName: string) {
    return new Promise<MicrosoftGraph.Channel>(async (resolve, reject) => {
      this.context.msGraphClientFactory
        .getClient()
        .then((client: MSGraphClient) =>{
          client
            .api(`/teams/${teamId}/channels`)
            .filter(`displayName eq '${channelName}'`)
            .version("beta")
            .get((error, response: any) => {
              if ( response.value.length == 1) {
                const channels: MicrosoftGraph.Channel[] = response.value;
                resolve(channels[0]);
              } else if (response.value.length < 1) {
                reject(new Error("No team found with the configured name"));
              } else {
                reject(new Error("Error XY"));
              }
            });
          })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          reject(error);
        });
    });
  }
```

I call this function like this:

```
  public getConversations(teamName: string, channelName: string, messageLimitTopics: number = 0, messageLimitResponses: number = 0) {
    return new Promise<any>(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        this.getTeamGroupByName(teamName)
          .then((teamGroup: MicrosoftGraph.Group) => {
            const teamId: string = teamGroup.id;
            this.getTeamChannelByName(teamId, channelName)
              .then((teamChannel: MicrosoftGraph.Channel) => {
                const channelId: string = teamChannel.id;
                this.getChannelTopicMessages(teamId, channelId, messageLimitTopics)
                  .then((messages: MicrosoftGraph.Message[]) => {
                    const numberOfMessages = messages.length;
                    ... // omitted
                  });
              });
          });
      } catch(error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  }
```

And this `getConversations()` function itself is called from my webpart code:

```
  public getConversations() {
    if (this.props.teamName && this.props.teamName.length > 0 &&
        this.props.channelName && this.props.channelName.length > 0) {
      GraphService.getConversations(this.props.teamName, this.props.channelName, this.props.messageLimitTopics, this.props.messageLimitResponses)
          .then((conversations) => {
              .. // omitted
          })
          .catch((err: Error) => {
            console.log(err);
            this.setState({errorMessage: err.message});
          });
    } else {
      // Mandatory settings are missing
      this.setState({errorMessage: strings.MandatorySettingsMissing});
    }
  }
```

So, as you can see, above, I want to write out the error (message) I receive from the `reject` inside  the `getConversations()` functions. The problem is, that I don't receive this rejection with the error, but in the console I see the following:

```
Uncaught Error: No team found with the configured name
```

I added the `.catch()` blocks you see above inside `getTeamChannelByName()` but this doesn't get hit during debugging.

Haven't worked much with promises and I am still confused a bit about them, so I guess that I probably have constructed the promise chain wrongly, maybe placed the catch block(s) in the wrong position(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at common mistakes done with Promises and I certainly had what is called a "Promise Hell".

So, I am not 100% sure yet, but I guess, the result of this was that there was no catch block for my `.then("Promise")` so the rejection went to nowhere.

I have now changed the calling method to this, and I also removed the try/catch blocks, as it is unnecessary:

```
public getConversations(teamName: string, channelName: string, messageLimitTopics: number = 0, messageLimitResponses: number = 0) {
    return new Promise<any>(async (resolve, reject) => {
      let teamId: string = null;
      let channelId: string = null;
      this.getTeamGroupIdByName(teamName)
        .then(tId => {
          teamId = tId;
          return this.getTeamChannelIdByName(teamId,channelName);
        })
        .then(cId => {
          channelId = cId;
          return this.getChannelTopicMessages(teamId, channelId, messageLimitTopics);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          reject(error);
        });
    });
  }
```